# Cross-site Scritping

Tags: angular, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

We are getting in trouble with Cross-Site Scritpting on an App we are working on.

Our App is coded in Angular 2, which we hosted in AWS s3 as an static website. This App is connected to an Backend which is behind an AWS API Gateway.

Our Frontend cant make any api calls, cause of Cross-site Scritping.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/web-acl-xss-conditions.html#web-acl-xss-conditions-values

I tried myself on this one but it wont work for me. Local Front- and Backend can communicate and both of them Works perefectly on there own.

Is there a good and not too advanced way to handle this Problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you validating URL parameters? XSS checkers complain about this because it might try to send JavaScript markup in the URL. If we don't sanitize the string by stripping of dangerous tags, it is possible to inject malicious script here.

Comment: @RaviChandra , How can i validate them? Over AWS? I have not much knowledge of this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also easily activate CORS using the AWS Console. See this guide for [more details on enabling CORS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html).

Answer (score 2):

Did you activate CORS on your API gateway?
I have exactly the same kind of application, and in API gateway you need to activate CORS: 
On your resource linked to a lambda (in POST, it'es mandatory if I remember well) you add the OPTION method. 
Here is an example in python of how programmatically activate the CORS:

```js
gateway = boto3.client('apigateway', region_name=self.conf.region)
gateway.put_method(
     restApiId=apiId,
     resourceId=resourceId,
     httpMethod="OPTIONS",
     authorizationType="NONE"
)

gateway.put_method_response(
 restApiId=apiId,
 resourceId=resourceId,
 httpMethod="OPTIONS",
 statusCode="200",
 responseParameters={
   'method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers': True,
   'method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin': True,
   'method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods': True 
},
responseModels={
  'application/json': 'Empty'
}
   )

gateway.put_integration(
    restApiId=api['id'],
    resourceId=apiResource['id'],
    httpMethod="OPTIONS",
    type="MOCK",
    requestTemplates={
        'application/json': '{"statusCode": 200}'
 }
)

gateway.put_integration_response(
    restApiId=api['id'],
    resourceId=apiResource['id'],
    httpMethod="OPTIONS",
    statusCode="200",
    selectionPattern=".*",
    responseParameters={
     "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'",
     "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "'*'",
     "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "'*'"
    },
    responseTemplates={
     'application/json': ''
    }
)  

gateway.put_method_response(
  restApiId=apiId,
  resourceId=resourceId,
  httpMethod="POST",
  statusCode=200,
  responseParameters={'method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin': True},
  responseModels={'application/json': 'Empty'}
```